# Insert data into new table from 2 tables, error duplicate destination name - Access Sql

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have 2 queries, the result of which I'm trying to insert into a new table.

```
Query1:   Class  Name    Age    City
           A1     Jill    21     New York

Query2:   Class   Name    Age    City
           A2      Joe     25     Paris
```

Now, the city can change when I run the queries again, but I want to insert into the new table only record with city = "New York".

So, something like INSERT INTO FinalTable(Name, Age, City)

```
SELECT 
    QUERY1.CLASS, QUERY1.NAME, QUERY1.AGE, QUERY1.CITY, 
    QUERY2.CLASS, QUERY2.NAME, QUERY2.AGE, QUERY2.CITY 
FROM QUERY1, QUERY2
WHERE (QUERY1.CITY="NEW YORK" OR QUERY2.CITY="NEW YORK")
```

Only 1 query will have city as New York on one iteration.

I get a duplicate destination name error

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago)

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

```
INSERT INTO FinalTable(Name, Age, City)
SELECT tab.* FROM(
  SELECT 
    QUERY1.CLASS, QUERY1.NAME, QUERY1.AGE, QUERY1.CITY, 
  FROM QUERY1
  WHERE QUERY1.CITY="NEW YORK"  
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 
    QUERY2.CLASS, QUERY2.NAME, QUERY2.AGE, QUERY2.CITY 
  FROM QUERY2
  WHERE QUERY2.CITY="NEW YORK"
) tab
```

Comment: Sorry you, I am not understand your question because "Query3" did not describe in your question.